# Unknown version of Tomcat was specified....Permission denied in accessing /opt/tomcat/bin

Tags: tomcat

Trying to setup my server in eclipse, and when I put in my tomcat installation directory, the next/finish buttons are still muted and eclipse says "Unknown version of Tomcat was specified."

[Muted Next and Finish buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqYVI.png)

Although I am logged in as user (which has sudo privileges) I am getting Permission denied error. I changed the ownership of `/opt/tomcat/bin` directory to the user tomcat which I created following instructiongs from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04#conclusion.

The command `$echo CATALINA_HOME` returns nothing.

Can anybody help me in this problem?

Comment: Permission denied trying to do what, exactly?

Comment: Trying to add tomcat server to Eclipse..when i specify the tomcat installation directory in Eclipse...the "Next" and "Finish" buttons are still muted..and eclipse says  "Unknown version of Tomcat was specified."...Also when I run $echo CATALINA_HOME....it returns nothing

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify which version of tomcat you're trying to install. It might indeed be a non supported version. If it isn't: for installation in eclipse, make the tomcat directory owned by you, e.g the user that is running eclipse. You're running a development system, not a productive server in eclipse.

Eclipse doesn't care if you can sudo our not, that's the wrong path.

If this all doesn't help, you'll need to add more detailed steps to reproduce